# How to diagnose why the JVM ends unexpectedly

Tags: java, jvm, sbt

I do the build process by means of [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org), with a lot of parallelism.
Sometimes, SBT dies and by looking at its console output it doesn't tell the cause.

I have made an exit hook in the JVM, and it is called.
So, I discard the JVM is crashing.

How can I diagnose the cause?.
Maybe someone is calling `System.exit()`, or the memory is exhausted.

If I repeat the build, then it succeeds.  It is a quite deterministic process, except for the mentioned problem I'm experiencing.

It fails about 5 or 10% of times.

**UPDATE 1**:

One idea is to use the [-XX:onError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html#CHDFEJBB) option of the JVM.

I already have this code (in Scala language) when booting the JVM, in order to diagnose who is killing the JVM:

```
System setSecurityManager new SecurityManager() {
    override def checkPermission(perm: Permission) = {}

    override def checkPermission(perm: Permission, context: scala.Any) = {}

    override def checkExit(status: Int) = {
        super.checkExit(status)
        println("Trying to exit from: ")
        Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace.foreach { p ⇒
            println(p.toString)
        }
    }
}
```

but no output is shown.

I'm using Linux (CentOS 7)

Comment: have you tried strace (if on Linux)?

Comment: You could add a security manager to [prevent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549720/how-to-prevent-calls-to-system-exit-from-terminating-the-jvm) a `System.exit` and watch till it occurs to ascertain if that's the reason.

Comment: See [Finding out who calls jvm shutdown hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091522/finding-out-who-calls-jvm-shutdown-hook)

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable tips.