# JVM exits with window visible when main invoked by reflection

Tags: java, swing, jvm, swingworker

Mac OS X Catalina

JDK OpenJDK 14.0.2 (same issue 14.0.1)

```
public class PriceUpdateForm extends JPanel {
/* lots of code omitted */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> startGUI());
        /* try {
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.exit(17);
        } */
    }

    private static void startGUI() {
        final var form = new PriceUpdateForm();
        form.j = new JFrame();
        form.j.getContentPane().add(form);
        form.j.pack();
        form.j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        form.j.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When this class's `main` method is invoked directly from the command line (or IntelliJ), it works as expected, even with the sleep commented out. The window stays visible until you click the close button, and then the program exits.

When, instead, I use a trampoline pattern where the class name is the first argument as shown below, the JVM is willing to exit even with the window visible. I had a hard time debugging this when the window disappeared right away, but if you uncomment the sleep, the JVM will exit after 3 seconds, with the window clearly visible until then.

**Excerpt from main method of Trampoline**

```
            final Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName(args[0]);
            final Method mainMethod = mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", newArgs.getClass());
            mainMethod.invoke(null, new Object[]{newArgs});
```

`newargs` is just the original arguments minus the zeroth.

I get that without the sleep, the `PriceUpdateForm.main` is going to exit, but I don’t see why it takes the Window down with it. That’s been created on the GUI thread. It is *not* going out of scope, or, at least, its scope should be the same no matter how `main` was called: directly or by reflection.

Can someone explain this difference in behavior? I suppose I can make a years-long `sleep`, but that seems ugly.

Comment: It’s hard to believe that this reflective invocation affects the behavior, as it’s not different to how the standard Java launcher invokes the main method (afaik, it uses `getMethod` instead of `getDeclaredMethod` but that’s it). Perhaps, the surrounding code of the reflective invocation is important. Btw, instead of `newArgs.getClass()` you can simply use `String[].class`.

Comment: @Holger I commented out everything except the array copy into the new arguments. Same behavior.

Comment: What happens if you invoke the method without Reflection, i.e. `PriceUpdateForm.main(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length));`, without any surrounding code? How about posting the complete code (even when you “commented out everything”, there still must be a surrounding class and method declaration)?

Comment: Depending on what triggers the JVM shutdown, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42092442/2711488) (and the other answer of that Q&A) may help.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've found the problem in the Trampoline class. Very helpful comments.